# Define specific JDK version for each dependency in maven pom

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, unsupported-class-version

I have Spring Web Service application run on Tomcat 7. I use Spring 4.3 version. Tomcat 7 run on Java Platform 1.7.
This is maven plugin configuration.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    ...    
    <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.0.2</version>
         <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
          <skip>true</skip>
         </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I change Java Platform 1.6 for Tomcat 7 and build and re-deploy the app, I got `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/ws/config/annotation/EnableWs : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 (unable to load class org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs)
```

I think Spring EnableWs class is compiled with latest JDK. Is that correct? I would like to change `JDK version for maven dependencies` to be compatible with Tomcat 7's JDK version 1.6. Is that possible?

Comment: Not without rebuilding and packaging the code yourself, which may be impossible if the library requires a specific version of Java.  The dependency is to a compiled code library, not source.

Comment: So I need to download Spring Source and compile with JDK 6 and package it again?

Comment: It probably won't work. Spring bends over backwards to support the oldest JDK it can, and if you are using a version that requires 1.7, that's because it's using 1.7 features. Even 1.7 is about to get dropped in Spring 5.

Comment: You should try rebuilding YOUR project with Java 8 and running everything under a Java 8 JVM.  Since Java is mostly backwards compatible that will probably work.  I'm relatively certain Tomcat will have no problem running under Java 8 even if built for Java 6.  It's going the other way that is a problem, usually.

Comment: @JimGarrison My problem is Production Server which is running on JDK 1.6. So I have no chance to upgrade the JDK.

Comment: JDK 1.6 has been end-of-life since February 2013. You cannot use newer libraries with it that require 1.7 or later. If the source uses features from 1.7 or later you cannot even build the libraries. Time to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring Ws Core 2.3.0 version, JDK 1.7+ required. Can not run on a tomcat with jdk 1.6